# GC time in spark executor dashboard

Tags: java, apache-spark

In spark executor dashboard page,

[image]

This is a bit confusing

Task time refers to the sum of all the task that ran in this executor. It's not weighted against the number of cores. so 14.2 / 8 ( 8 cores in my machine ) = 1.75h is equal to the uptime of the executor  ( wall clock )

I want to know, for the GC time mentioned, is this the sum as well as accumulated by each thread within the executor? Do I have to divide it by 8 to get a rough estimate of the amount of time the executor as a whole was undergoing GC?

Since we use ParallelGC, we want to know if my executor was in stop the world for 41min or 41/8=5min ?

Answer (score 0):

GC time is the total JVM garbage collection time. Refer to the below documentation.
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html][1]

Also, same metrics can be collected using SparkListeners, where we will get to know how much time is spent on each task [cpu time + gc time + serialization time etc.] that gives more insights. Informative post.
https://medium.com/@hareesha1906/apache-spark-job-monitoring-f2332ef50915

Comment: well it is still not clear to me. like i said, task time is sum of each task the executor ran. each task has its own gc time. is that gc time sum of all task gc time? e.g. if a executor ran 2 task with time t1, t2 and gc1,gc2 then task time in web ui is t1+t2 in executor. is the gc time gc1+gc2? or is it gc3 which is the actual gc time of the jvm overall ?

Comment: I think it is over all, in the executor dashboard, the metrics are not given per task.Like how Task time per executor is given, gc time is also per executor which is jvm gc time. The way I would check to confirm is get task level metrics(per executor ) printed to console or to logs.

Comment: Ok, time to experiment i guess :)